# Script to check status and start service if required

Tags: powershell, windows-services, windows-server-2008, configurationmanager, sccm

Need help in writing a PowerShell script to check the status of a service and start if it is stopped. the services are: NomadBranch, BITS, Ccmexec.

Answer (score 3):

SO is not a place where people write code for you, nor is it a replacement for a tutorial (or a place for finding one). However, since your question is simple enough I'll answer anyway. Don't expect this to happen often, though.

Use the `*-Service` cmdlets for managing services. `Get-Service -Name 'foo'` gets the properties of a service named "foo". `Start-Service -Name 'foo'` starts that service, `Stop-Service -Name 'foo'` stops it.

You can find stopped services by filtering the output of `Get-Service` for the ones with the status `Stopped`, and start stopped services by piping the filtered result into `Start-Service`:

```bsh
$services = 'NomadBranch', 'BITS', 'Ccmexec'

Get-Service | Where-Object {
    $services -contains $_.Name -and $_.Status -eq 'Stopped'
} | Start-Service
```

Use the `Get-Command` cmdlet to list the cmdlets for a particular noun (here: "Service"):

```bsh
Get-Command -Noun 'Service'
```

and use the `Get-Help` cmdlet to get more information about a particular cmdlet, e.g.:

```bsh
Get-Help Get-Service -Full
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey man below is a function to start a service

```
Function Start-ServicesNotRunning(){ 
    param 
    ( 
      [string[]]$ServerNames =$(throw "Parameter missing: -ServerNames ServerName1,ServerName2") #get multiple services 
    ) 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Get Services State..." 
    Get-Service -Name $ServerNames | Sort-Object Status,Displayname  |  
    ForEach-Object { 
        $Displayname = $_.Displayname 
        If($_.Status -eq "Running") 
        {  
           Write-Host $Displayname $_.Status -ForegroundColor Green 
        } Else 
        { 
           Write-Host $Displayname $_.Status $_.StartType -ForegroundColor Red 
           Try 
           { 
               #server startup status is disabled. 
               If($_.StartType -eq "Disabled") 
               {    
                  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $Displayname "Startup Status To Manual..." 
                  Set-Service -Name $_.Name -StartupType Manual -ErrorAction Stop 
               }  
               #start it if not running 
               Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $Displayname "Starting..." 

               Start-Service -InputObject $_ -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop 
               $_.Refresh() 
               Write-Host $Displayname $_.Status -ForegroundColor Green 
           } 
           Catch 
           { 
              Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $Displayname $_.Exception.Message 
           } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I pick it from a this sample, https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-get-state-and-start-b54c3b9c Hopefully it can help.